# on_press event in kivy button not working as expected

Tags: python, kivy

Below is small snippet from my code .

issue:- get function is call when a screen "X" is loaded and some params are passed. In get i am create buttons with some names and assigning  on_press event. But issue is on_press event is called automatically without pressing button and next screen comes into picture.

```
   def get(self, service):
            """ some code"""
            but = Button(size_hint=(1, None))
            but.text = str(i['name'][0][:10])
            but.bind(on_press = self.change_screen(dict))
            print "adding widget to home  "  + str(but)
            self.home_box.add_widget(but)

    def change_screen(self, dict):
        self.screen_manager.current = 'Per_settings'
```

Any idea whats happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
but.bind(on_press = self.change_screen(dict))
```

You're calling `self.change_screen(dict)` - this is normal python syntax for a function call, the bind method doesn't even know about it and is only passed the result of the call.

You must pass the function itself. You can use functools.partial to automatically include the argument, though note that bind also passes extra arguments.

```
from functools import partial
but.bind(on_press=partial(self.change_screen, dict))
```

Comment: thanks @inclement that works fine, thinking of taking lesson from you